# In html, how to stretch an image in only one dimension?

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I want to fit an 10*60 image into a 15*15 container. That is to say, I want to stretch my image so that the width correspond (so that would be an image of 15*90), but I do not want the height to stretch more than the width, so the bottom of my image will not appear.

When I define my html image, I put an width=100% to stretch the width, but what do I say to the height?

Thank  you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a background image and set its background-size property to contain (or cover, depends what you need).

```css
.container {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x300) no-repeat center center orange;
  background-size: contain;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes changewidth {
  from {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also position the image absolute, so you can do something like this:

.embed.ratio-16-9
  img

```
.embed {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;

  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
.ratio-16-9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

The image height should no longer be stuck to you block.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS background-image with background-size: cover**

You should use CSS background-image property for this kind of styling your web elements.

What you're looking for is probably the `background-size: cover;`. What it does is it fits the image based on width of the container.

CSS:

```
.cont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('urlToImage100x300.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cont"></div>
```

Also, if you want to center your image vertically use `background-position-y: center;`.

```
.cont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('urlToImage100x300.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: center;
}
```

---

**HTML img tag**

If you really need to use an `<img />` tag for this operation; What you need is to put the image into container, then set the `width`, `height` to your desired size and `overflow-y` to hidden. After that, set the `width` of an img to 100% and it's done.

CSS:

```
.cont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.cont img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cont"><img src="image100x300.jpg" /></div>
```

Working demo CSS w/o y-axis center: https://jsfiddle.net/e2vt3sw6/

Working demo CSS w/ y-axis center: https://jsfiddle.net/e2vt3sw6/1/

Working demo HTML img tag: https://jsfiddle.net/e2vt3sw6/2/

Tests where made using 150x300px image and 200x200px container

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you don't have to specify any value on the `height` property. Just set `overflow:hidden` on your container if you don't want the overflowing part of the image to show. Hope this helps.